# Dimension of the secant variety $\sigma_2 (\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensors, tensor-rank

I am trying to compute the dimension of the secant variety $\sigma_2 (\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)$, for this I want to use the Terracini Lemma, that says that $$
T_p\sigma_2 (\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)= \langle T_x(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1),T_y(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)~\rangle.
$$
The expected dimension is $9$.

What I tried to do was to utilize the Segre embedding $$\sigma:\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\rightarrow \mathbb P(\mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2),
$$
and now this space corresponds to the projetivization of rank 1 tensors in $\mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2$.

So a curve on this space is given by $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2$, $\gamma(t)=a(t)\otimes b(t)\otimes c(t)\otimes d(t)$. Computing the tangent space to $x=\gamma(0)=a\otimes b\otimes c\otimes d$, we have that $$
T_x(C(\sigma(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)))=\mathbb C^2\otimes b\otimes c\otimes d+\dots +a\otimes b \otimes c \otimes \mathbb C^2,
$$
So via Terracini I would have that $$T_p\sigma_2(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)=\langle T_x\sigma(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1), T_y\sigma(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)~\rangle
$$
I cannot see what I am missing. Any suggestion or tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four 2-dimensional summands of $T_x$ in your formula all contain the 1-dimensional space $a \otimes b \otimes c \otimes d$. Consequently, their sum is 5-dimensional.

Comment: But how do I guarantee that these two spaces $T_{x}\sigma(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)$ and $T_{y}\sigma(\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1)$ are independent, i.e. that their dimension sum is 9?

Comment: For instance, compute in a basis.

Comment: Assume that $x=a\otimes b\otimes c\otimes d$ and $y=e\otimes f\otimes g\otimes h$, we can choose basis for each of the $\mathbb C^2$ st $a=b=c=d=e_1$ and because $p$ has rank $2$, $e=f=e_2$ without lost of generality. Then I can show that it has dimension 10 given that $g\neq \lambda e_1$ and $h\neq \mu e_1$. This means in a set of dimension one in the cone, i.e. the points $ p=e_1\otimes e_1 \otimes e_1\otimes e_1+\lambda e_2\otimes e_2\otimes e_1\otimes e_1$, it does not have the expected dimension, does this means that the dimension of the space is $9$ since at a general point it is $9$?